# Hide popover if value is undefined in Angular 6

Tags: angular6, popover

I am using ngx-popover for tooltip in Angular 6. Everything is working fine but if am getting empty value then also its showing empty popver

My code is :

```
<div class="vertical sub-child active{{item._id}}" [ngClass]="{'shortlen': item.category.length>36 }" 
                        popover="{{item.description}}"
                            popoverPlacement="right"
                            [popoverOnHover]="true"
                            [popoverCloseOnClickOutside]="true"
                            [popoverCloseOnMouseOutside]="true"
                            [popoverDisabled]="false"
                            [popoverAnimation]="true"> {{item.category}} </div>
```

{{item.description}} is empty sometimes at that time my tooltip have to disappear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `item.description` is `undefined`, or an empty string, it's falsy, so you can use the existence of a value to determine the `[popoverDisabled]` attribute. To be doubly sure, you can use the bang, bang boolean approach (`!!`) along with it, although it shouldn't strictly be required.

```
<div class="vertical sub-child active{{item._id}}" [ngClass]="{'shortlen': item.category.length>36 }" 
                    popover="{{item.description}}"
                        popoverPlacement="right"
                        [popoverOnHover]="true"
                        [popoverCloseOnClickOutside]="true"
                        [popoverCloseOnMouseOutside]="true"
                        [popoverDisabled]="!!item.description"
                        [popoverAnimation]="true"> {{item.category}} </div>
```

Alternatively, if there are other keys in `item` that may be empty, and require the popover hidden, use a function in your component instead;

```
<div class="vertical sub-child active{{item._id}}" [ngClass]="{'shortlen': item.category.length>36 }" 
        popover="{{item.description}}"
        popoverPlacement="right"
        [popoverOnHover]="true"
        [popoverCloseOnClickOutside]="true"
        [popoverCloseOnMouseOutside]="true"
        [popoverDisabled]="hasRequiredValues(item)"
        [popoverAnimation]="true"> {{item.category}} </div>
```

In your component;

```
/**
 * Do all your data tests here, and return the result
 */
hasRequiredValues(item: Item) {
   return !!item.description && !!item.category;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for you response.. Its working for some category,But not working for all

Comment: Your question was about `item.description`, not `item.category`... 

Comment: ya description only .. Now its working. I tried like this    [popoverDisabled]="item.description == '' || !item.description "

Comment: Ya description only..I have to hover on the category then it have to show description

Comment: See updated answer for situations where there are other required values to determine if pop-over should work. :)